# I think my gas boiler flue looks off

Tags: gas, boiler, natural-gas, building-regulations, flue

We had a gas boiler installed. The registered installer did not highlight any issues with fitting the boiler before fitting it. I was away when the job was done and now there is a "snorkel" never mentioned pre work up on my front wall on the street.

[image: snorkel]

He has drilled the hole for the flue ca 1.75m high. Apparently the neighbours complained about the vapour going in their door (we were never notified of neighbours complaint by the installer at the timw of the incident) and to satisfy the neighours (?) such extension was installed. Is that normal as to me this looks very odd solution. Could the exhaust pipe come out from boiler in another angle and could we then have the pipe going up inside the wall and exiting higher to the outside with the "traditional flue opening"? (It cannot go straight up as it is solid stone wall just above it).

Comment: Get some matching paint and it will blend in like the other pipe.

Comment: Yes, that looks probably correct. That pipe exhausts carbon monoxide along with other chemicals. There should be various codes in place about minimum distance from a window or door which it needs to terminate. Is this a new system or was there an existing boiler in that spot?

Comment: It is a new system just installed. The flue has to be minimum 30 cm from a.boundary wall and that is what it is. I do see my neighbour's upser as this apparently was going in their window and door

Answer (score 1):

Assuming it's a UK installation, then "snorkels" aren't unusual.  They are required to prevent exhaust gases from entering through windows, or doors in this case.

You can't have the flue running up inside the wall, as current regulations require it to be inspectable over it's entire length, to ensure that the flue segments aren't coming apart.

Unless you're willing to do some building work, there don't seem to be many options open to you.